# Jquery change function not working in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){             
$("#agegrade").change(function () {                   
var str = "";                   
$("select option:selected").each(function () {               
str = $(this).text();               
if(str == "1900-1903")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1904-1907")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1908-1911")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1912-1915")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1916-1919")                  
str = "EGBE NA UGO";
else if(str == "1920-1923")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1924-1927")                  
str = "IGWEBUIKE";               
else if(str == "1928-1931")                  
str = "ANYILIGWE";
else if(str == "1932-1935")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1936-1939")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1940-1943")                  
str = "UCHE BU UKO";
else if(str == "1944-1947")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
else if(str == "1948-1951")                  
str = "OFU OBI";               
else if(str == "1952-1955")                  
str = "ANULIKA";
else if(str == "1956-1959")                  
str = "IFUNANYA";               
else if(str == "1960-1963")                  
str = "NWANNEKA";               
else if(str == "1964-1967")                  
str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";
else if(str == "1968-1971")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
else if(str == "1972-1975")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
else if(str == "1976-1979")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
else if(str == "1980-1983")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
else if(str == "1984-1987")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
else if(str == "1988-1991")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
else if(str == "1992-1995")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
else if(str == "1996-1999")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
else if(str == "2000-2003")                  
str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";                              
else
str = "Please Select An Item";
                       });                   
$("#adiv").text(str);
 })                 
 .change();         
 });
 </script> 
<select id="agegrade" name="agegrade" multiple="multiple">          
<option  selected="selected">1900-1903</option>
<option>1904-1907</option>
<option>1908-1911</option>
<option>1912-1915</option>
<option>1916-1919</option>
<option>1920-1923</option>
<option>1924-1927</option>
<option>1928-1931</option>
<option>1932-1935</option>
<option>1936-1939</option>
<option>1940-1943</option>
<option>1944-1947</option>
<option>1948-1951</option>
<option>1952-1955</option>
<option>1956-1959</option>
<option>1960-1963</option>
<option>1964-1967</option>
<option>1968-1971</option>
<option>1972-1975</option>
<option>1976-1979</option>
<option>1980-1983</option>
<option>1984-1987</option>
<option>1988-1991</option>
<option>1992-1995</option>
<option>1996-1999</option>
<option>2000-2003</option>
</select>
<div id="adiv"></div>
```

The above code works, but when I try to include it on the form (registration form) where I want to apply it, it doesn't work. What could be the cause? Please help me fix this. Below is the code. Also, the date function doesn't work.

```
<table width="815" height="1000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr align="left">
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Registration Page</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Title: </strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="title" id="title">
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
<option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
<option value="Barr.">Barr.</option>
<option value="Engr">Engr</option>
<option value="Justice">Justice</option>
<option value="Evang">Evang</option>
<option value="Arch">Arch</option>
<option value="Chief">Chief</option>
<option value="Hon">Hon</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect1">
<label for="title"></label>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
<tr align="left"></tr>
<tr>
<td width="167" align="left"><strong>Surname:</strong></td>
<td width="648" align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield1">
<label for="surname"></label>
<input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your surname is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Other Names:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="othernames"></label>
<input name="othernames" type="text" id="othernames" size="51" maxlength="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Date Of Birth:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="dob"></label>
<span id="sprytextfield9">
<label for="dateofbirth"></label>
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span> (format dd/mm/yyyy)                    <tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Father's Name:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield6">
<label for="fathersname"></label>
<input name="fathersname" type="text" id="fathersname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your father's name is required.</span></span></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Mother's Name:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield7">
<label for="mothersname"></label>
<input name="mothersname" type="text" id="mothersname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your mother's name  is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Ward:      </strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect2">
<label for="ward"></label>
<select name="ward" id="ward">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
<option value="AdagbeMmimi">AdagbeMmimi</option>
<option value="Aga">Aga</option>
<option value="Anugama">Anugama</option>
<option value="Esike">Esike</option>
<option value="Etele">Etele</option>
<option value="Mmimi">Mmimi</option>
<option value="Eziakpaka">Eziakpaka</option>
<option value="Okpalo/Nwadika">Okpalo/Nwadika</option>
<option value="Ugwaku/Mgbike">Ugwaku/Mgbike</option>
<option value="Umukwa">Umukwa</option>
<option value="JikoroUfele">JikoroUfele</option>
<option value="Omesu">Omesu</option>
<option value="Umuezunu">Umuezunu</option>
<option value="Urualo/Uruejimofor">Urualo/Uruejimofor</option>
<option value="Urukpaleri">Urukpaleri</option>
<option value="Uruoji">Uruoji</option>
</select>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select a ward.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Village:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect3">
<label for="village"></label>
<select name="village" id="village">
<option selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="Iridana">Iridana</option>
<option value="Mmimi">Mmimi</option>
<option value="Umuezeunu">Umuezeunu</option>
<option value="Umukwa">Umukwa</option>
<option value="EnugoMmimi">EnugoMmimi</option>
<option value="UmumriamObunese">UmumriamObunese</option>
<option value="Urualo">Urualo</option>
<option value="Uruejimofor">Uruejimofor</option>
<option value="Urukpaleri">Urukpaleri</option>
<option value="Uruoji">Uruoji</option>
</select>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select a village.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Age Grade:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect4" />
<label for="agegrade"></label>
<select name="agegrade" id="agegrade">          
<option selected="selected">1900-1903</option>
<option>1904-1907</option>
<option>1908-1911</option>
<option>1912-1915</option>
<option>1916-1919</option>
<option>1920-1923</option>
<option>1924-1927</option>
<option>1928-1931</option>
<option>1932-1935</option>
<option>1936-1939</option>
<option>1940-1943</option>
<option>1944-1947</option>
<option>1948-1951</option>
<option>1952-1955</option>
<option>1956-1959</option>
<option>1960-1963</option>
<option>1964-1967</option>
<option>1968-1971</option>
<option>1972-1975</option>
<option>1976-1979</option>
<option>1980-1983</option>
<option>1984-1987</option>
<option>1988-1991</option>
<option>1992-1995</option>
<option>1996-1999</option>
<option>2000-2003</option>
</select>
<script>         
    $(document).ready(function(){             
    $("#agegrade").change(function () {                   
    var str = "";                   
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {               
    str = $(this).text();               
    if(str == "1900-1903")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1904-1907")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1908-1911")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1912-1915")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1916-1919")                  
    str = "EGBE NA UGO";
    else if(str == "1920-1923")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1924-1927")                  
    str = "IGWEBUIKE";               
    else if(str == "1928-1931")                  
    str = "ANYILIGWE";
    else if(str == "1932-1935")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1936-1939")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1940-1943")                  
    str = "UCHE BU UKO";
    else if(str == "1944-1947")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
    else if(str == "1948-1951")                  
    str = "OFU OBI";               
    else if(str == "1952-1955")                  
    str = "ANULIKA";
    else if(str == "1956-1959")                  
    str = "IFUNANYA";               
    else if(str == "1960-1963")                  
    str = "NWANNEKA";               
    else if(str == "1964-1967")                  
    str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";
    else if(str == "1968-1971")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
    else if(str == "1972-1975")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
    else if(str == "1976-1979")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
    else if(str == "1980-1983")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
    else if(str == "1984-1987")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
    else if(str == "1988-1991")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
    else if(str == "1992-1995")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
    else if(str == "1996-1999")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
    else if(str == "2000-2003")                  
    str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";                              
    else
    str = "Please Select An Item";
                           });                   
    $("#adiv").text(str);
     })                 
     .change();         
     });

</script>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="167" align="left"><strong>Name Of Age Grade:</strong></td>
<td width="648" align="left" valign="middle">
<label for="NAgegrade"></label>
<input name="NAgegrade" type="text" id="NAgegrade" size="51" maxlength="40" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Occupation:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect5">
<label for="occupation"></label>
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
<option selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="Architect">Architect</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
<option value="Student">Student</option>
<option value="Scientist">Scientist</option>
<option value="Farmer">Farmer</option>
<option value="Lawyer">Lawyer</option>
<option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
<option value="Professor">Professor</option>
<option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
<option value="Lecturer">Lecturer</option>
<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
<option value="Civil Servant">Civil Servant</option>
<option value="Judge">Judge</option>
<option value="Pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
<option value="Educationist">Educationist</option>
<option value="Surveyor">Surveyor</option>
<option value="Ploice Officer">Ploice Officer</option>
<option value="Military Officer">Military Officer</option>
<option value="Custom Officer">Custom Officer</option>
<option value="Immigration Officer">Immigration Officer</option>
<option value="others">Others Please specify...</option>
</select>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield2">
<label for="phonenumber"></label>
<input name="phonenumber" type="text" id="phonenumber" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your Phone Number  is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Email Address:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield3">
<label for="email"></label>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your Email  is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Country Of Residence:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect6">
<label for="country"></label>
<select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name="country"></select>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>State Of Residence:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield4">
<label for="state"></label>
<select name="state" id="state"></select>
<script language="javascript">print_country("country");</script>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>City Of Residence:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield5">
<label for="city"></label>
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your city is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Address(Optional):</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextarea1">
<label for="address"></label>
<textarea name="address" id="address" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Create your username and password</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Username:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield8">
<label for="username"></label>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your username is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Password:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprypassword1">
<label for="password"></label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="51" maxlength="30" />
<span class="passwordMaxCharsMsg">Must be a maximum of 40 characters.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Verify Password:</strong></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryconfirm1">
<label for="password"></label>
<input name="password2" type="password" id="password" size="51" maxlength="40" />
<span class="confirmRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The values don't match.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @KevinBoucher +1 for the link. That was my first thought too!

Comment: Would it kill ya to properly indent & format your code?

Comment: switch is a horrible choice with you can just make these strings the "value" or "data" attribute of the option tags.

Comment: @Hogan To be honest, I really didn't get that far.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your scripts should usually, if not always, go at the bottom of the page between the closing HTML and closing body tag. This not only improves the performance of the page rendering, but also ensures that the necessary HTML elements have been rendered before any dependent scripts are executed.

Secondly, it's very difficult to sift through all that markup. Here's a condensed version of your script (see below). I made all the values into attributs of the options themselves. This significantly reduces the complexity of your code. Also, I wasn't sure why you were iterating over every value only to get the last selected one, so I modified it to get the last selected value directly.

Next, I would add the appropriate attributes to your script tags

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//... your code
</script>
```

Lastly, I don't see the div `<div id="adiv"></div>` on your form in the non-working example. Perhaps it was an omission from copying and pasting the code, but if not, then it is likely the cause of your problem.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4YEvf/4/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="agegrade" name="agegrade" multiple="multiple">          
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED' selected="selected">1900-1903</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1904-1907</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1908-1911</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1912-1915</option>
  <option value='EGBE NA UGO'>1916-1919</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1920-1923</option>
  <option value='IGWEBUIKE'>1924-1927</option>
  <option value='ANYILIGWE'>1928-1931</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1932-1935</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1936-1939</option>
  <option value='UCHE BU UKO'>1940-1943</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1944-1947</option>
  <option value='OFU OBI'>1948-1951</option>
  <option value='ANULIKA'>1952-1955</option>
  <option value='IFUNANYA'>1956-1959</option>
  <option value='NWANNEKA'>1960-1963</option>
  <option value='NAME TO BE PROVIDED'>1964-1967</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1968-1971</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1972-1975</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1976-1979</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1980-1983</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1984-1987</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1988-1991</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1992-1995</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>1996-1999</option>
  <option value='YET TO BE GROUPED'>2000-2003</option>
</select>
<div id="adiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){             
  $("#agegrade").change(function () {                           
    $("#adiv").text($("select option:selected:last").val());
  }).change();         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
      <table width="815" height="1000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr align="left">

        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Registration Page</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Title: </strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="title" id="title">
              <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
              <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
              <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
              <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
              <option value="Barr.">Barr.</option>
              <option value="Engr">Engr</option>
              <option value="Justice">Justice</option>
              <option value="Evang">Evang</option>
              <option value="Arch">Arch</option>
              <option value="Chief">Chief</option>
              <option value="Hon">Hon</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect1">
            <label for="title"></label>
            <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
        <tr align="left"></tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="167" align="left"><strong>Surname:</strong></td>
          <td width="648" align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield1">
              <label for="surname"></label>
              <input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your surname is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Other Names:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="othernames"></label>
            <input name="othernames" type="text" id="othernames" size="51" maxlength="40" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Date Of Birth:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="dob"></label>
            <span id="sprytextfield9">
              <label for="dateofbirth"></label>
              <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span> (format dd/mm/yyyy)                    <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Father's Name:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield6">
              <label for="fathersname"></label>
              <input name="fathersname" type="text" id="fathersname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your father's name is required.</span></span></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Mother's Name:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield7">
              <label for="mothersname"></label>
              <input name="mothersname" type="text" id="mothersname" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your mother's name  is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Ward:      </strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect2">
              <label for="ward"></label>
              <select name="ward" id="ward">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
                <option value="AdagbeMmimi">AdagbeMmimi</option>
                <option value="Aga">Aga</option>
                <option value="Anugama">Anugama</option>
                <option value="Esike">Esike</option>
                <option value="Etele">Etele</option>
                <option value="Mmimi">Mmimi</option>
                <option value="Eziakpaka">Eziakpaka</option>
                <option value="Okpalo/Nwadika">Okpalo/Nwadika</option>
                <option value="Ugwaku/Mgbike">Ugwaku/Mgbike</option>
                <option value="Umukwa">Umukwa</option>
                <option value="JikoroUfele">JikoroUfele</option>
                <option value="Omesu">Omesu</option>
                <option value="Umuezunu">Umuezunu</option>
                <option value="Urualo/Uruejimofor">Urualo/Uruejimofor</option>
                <option value="Urukpaleri">Urukpaleri</option>
                <option value="Uruoji">Uruoji</option>
              </select>
              <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select a ward.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Village:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect3">
              <label for="village"></label>
              <select name="village" id="village">
                <option selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="Iridana">Iridana</option>
                <option value="Mmimi">Mmimi</option>
                <option value="Umuezeunu">Umuezeunu</option>
                <option value="Umukwa">Umukwa</option>
                <option value="EnugoMmimi">EnugoMmimi</option>
                <option value="UmumriamObunese">UmumriamObunese</option>
                <option value="Urualo">Urualo</option>
                <option value="Uruejimofor">Uruejimofor</option>
                <option value="Urukpaleri">Urukpaleri</option>
                <option value="Uruoji">Uruoji</option>
              </select>
              <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select a village.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Age Grade:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect4" >
              <label for="agegrade"></label>
              <select name="agegrade" id="agegrade">       
                <option selected="selected">Please Select An Item</option>
                <option>1900-1903</option>
                <option>1904-1907</option>
                <option>1908-1911</option>
                <option>1912-1915</option>
                <option>1916-1919</option>
                <option>1920-1923</option>
                <option>1924-1927</option>
                <option>1928-1931</option>
                <option>1932-1935</option>
                <option>1936-1939</option>
                <option>1940-1943</option>
                <option>1944-1947</option>
                <option>1948-1951</option>
                <option>1952-1955</option>
                <option>1956-1959</option>
                <option>1960-1963</option>
                <option>1964-1967</option>
                <option>1968-1971</option>
                <option>1972-1975</option>
                <option>1976-1979</option>
                <option>1980-1983</option>
                <option>1984-1987</option>
                <option>1988-1991</option>
                <option>1992-1995</option>
                <option>1996-1999</option>
                <option>2000-2003</option>
              </select>
              <script>         
                $(document).ready(function(){             
                  $("#agegrade").live('change',function () {                   
                    var str = "";                   
                    $("#agegrade option:selected").text();              
                    str = $("#agegrade option:selected").text();               
                    if(str == "1900-1903")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1904-1907")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1908-1911")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1912-1915")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1916-1919")                  
                      str = "EGBE NA UGO";
                    else if(str == "1920-1923")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1924-1927")                  
                      str = "IGWEBUIKE";               
                    else if(str == "1928-1931")                  
                      str = "ANYILIGWE";
                    else if(str == "1932-1935")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1936-1939")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1940-1943")                  
                      str = "UCHE BU UKO";
                    else if(str == "1944-1947")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";               
                    else if(str == "1948-1951")                  
                      str = "OFU OBI";               
                    else if(str == "1952-1955")                  
                      str = "ANULIKA";
                    else if(str == "1956-1959")                  
                      str = "IFUNANYA";               
                    else if(str == "1960-1963")                  
                      str = "NWANNEKA";               
                    else if(str == "1964-1967")                  
                      str = "NAME TO BE PROVIDED";
                    else if(str == "1968-1971")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
                    else if(str == "1972-1975")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
                    else if(str == "1976-1979")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
                    else if(str == "1980-1983")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
                    else if(str == "1984-1987")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
                    else if(str == "1988-1991")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
                    else if(str == "1992-1995")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";               
                    else if(str == "1996-1999")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";
                    else if(str == "2000-2003")                  
                      str = "YET TO BE GROUPED";                              
                    else
                      str = "Please Select An Item";

                    $("#adiv").text(str);
                  })    
                });

              </script>
            <span id="adiv">Please select an item.</span></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="167" align="left"><strong>Name Of Age Grade:</strong></td>
          <td width="648" align="left" valign="middle">
            <label for="NAgegrade"></label>
            <input name="NAgegrade" type="text" id="NAgegrade" size="51" maxlength="40" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Occupation:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect5">
              <label for="occupation"></label>
              <select name="occupation" id="occupation">
                <option selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                <option value="Scientist">Scientist</option>
                <option value="Farmer">Farmer</option>
                <option value="Lawyer">Lawyer</option>
                <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                <option value="Professor">Professor</option>
                <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
                <option value="Lecturer">Lecturer</option>
                <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
                <option value="Civil Servant">Civil Servant</option>
                <option value="Judge">Judge</option>
                <option value="Pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
                <option value="Educationist">Educationist</option>
                <option value="Surveyor">Surveyor</option>
                <option value="Ploice Officer">Ploice Officer</option>
                <option value="Military Officer">Military Officer</option>
                <option value="Custom Officer">Custom Officer</option>
                <option value="Immigration Officer">Immigration Officer</option>
                <option value="others">Others Please specify...</option>
              </select>
              <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield2">
              <label for="phonenumber"></label>
              <input name="phonenumber" type="text" id="phonenumber" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your Phone Number  is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Email Address:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield3">
              <label for="email"></label>
              <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your Email  is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Country Of Residence:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryselect6">
              <label for="country"></label>
              <select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name="country"></select>
              <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>State Of Residence:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield4">
              <label for="state"></label>
              <select name="state" id="state"></select>
              <!--<script language="javascript">print_country("country");</script>-->
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>City Of Residence:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield5">
              <label for="city"></label>
              <input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your city is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Address(Optional):</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextarea1">
              <label for="address"></label>
              <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
            </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Create your username and password</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Username:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprytextfield8">
              <label for="username"></label>
              <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your username is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Password:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="sprypassword1">
              <label for="password"></label>
              <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="51" maxlength="30" />
              <span class="passwordMaxCharsMsg">Must be a maximum of 40 characters.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><strong>Verify Password:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="spryconfirm1">
              <label for="password"></label>
              <input name="password2" type="password" id="password" size="51" maxlength="40" />
              <span class="confirmRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The values don't match.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
          <td>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />

    </form>
```